# Apache HTTP returns cryptic error messages

Tags: centos, httpd, service

(Apache 2.4 / centOS 7)

I am trying to start httpd service, following the following commands:

```
[root@localhost ~]# service httpd start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

[root@localhost ~]# service httpd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  httpd.service
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2015-12-05 08:50:58 IRST; 4min 22s ago
  Process: 3858 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3856 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3856 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 05 08:50:58 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 05 08:50:58 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 05 08:50:58 localhost.localdomain kill[3858]: kill: cannot find process ""
Dec 05 08:50:58 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 05 08:50:58 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 05 08:50:58 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
```

I can start it using `httpd -k start`, what is wrong with the service?

Comment: Use `systemctl start/stop/status httpd`. CentOS-7 migrated to System from SysVinit system. What is the output for `systemctl status httpd` and what happens when you use `start`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 That old command are redirected to systemctl as written in the terminal.

Comment: Look at Apache's error log.